# Autofac can't resolve dependency

Tags: c#, autofac

I can't resolve registered type IQMService.

> Error：No accessible constructors were found for the type '__ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_gmbeg5il'.

Below is the code invoke Resolve:

```
public IQMService qMService;
public QMModule QMModule;
public PageBase() {
    qMService = AutofacDependency.Resolve<IQMService>();
    QMModule = new QMModule(qMService);
}
```

Definition of model:

```
public interface IQMService{
    somefunction()
}
public class QMService : IQMService{
    public QMService()
        {
          someprocess();
        }
}
```

Previously working code of AutofacDependency() defined:

```
static AutofacDependency()
        {
            Assembly[] assemblys = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies ();
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes (assemblys);
            builder.RegisterModule (new ConfigurationSettingsReader ("autofac"));
            container = builder.Build();
        }
```

After I upgrade .net from 4.0 to 4.8, and update autofac from 3.5.2 to 6.4.0, `ConfigurationSettingsReader` no longer exist, so I have to update the config file and change the code to below, not work,

```
static AutofacDependency()
        {
            Assembly[] assemblys = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies ();
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes (assemblys);
            //builder.RegisterModule (new ConfigurationSettingsReader ("autofac"));
            ConfigurationBuilder cfgbuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cfgbuilder.AddXmlFile("autofac.config");
            var module = new ConfigurationModule(cfgbuilder.Build());
            builder.RegisterModule(module);
            container = builder.Build();
        }
```

I also test this way

```
static AutofacDependency()
        {
            Assembly[] assemblys = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies ();
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes (assemblys);
            builder.RegisterType<Strix.QM.Service.QMService>().As<Strix.QM.Service.IQMService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            container = builder.Build();
        }
```

But I always get the error No accessible constructors were found even though I can it's defined. Thank you if any help, and if any necessary information missing please comment I will append it.

Answer (score 1):

The short version here is that this...

```cs
Assembly[] assemblys = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies ();
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes (assemblys);
```

...is really not something you should ever do. This literally registers *every type in the entire running system*, including everything in every .NET base library, into dependency injection. Be *way, way* more selective than that when registering. I'd bet if you remove that and *only* register the stuff you need, then DI won't try to resolve the odd .NET stuff that doesn't have accessible constructors.